# awk command giving "unterminated string" error

Tags: awk

When I am using awk command to insert a line it is giving  unterminated string error.

input file is like

```
date      mean       rms       bias                                       
.....    .....       ....      .......                                         
.....       .....        ........           .........                         
......        ........  .......           .......
```

Here I need to insert new values of date, mean, rms and bias.

my script is like this

```
echo $PDY $mean $rms  $bias                                      
awk '/Date/ { print; print "'$PDY' \t'$mean' \t'$rms' \t'$bias'"; next }1' file.txt
```

Terminal log is like this

```
+ echo 20180131 76.196 578.177 903.000                        
20180131 76.196 578.177 903.000
+ awk '/Date/ { print; print "20180131 \t' '76.196 \t578.177 \t903.000"; next }1' file.txt                                                      
awk: /Date/ { print; print "20180131 \t
awk:                       ^ unterminated string
```

There is a ' ' (gap/space) coming after `print; print "20180131 \t` in my awk command. I don't know why it is coming

Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string starts with `'` and ends with the second `'`:

```
awk '/Date/ { print; print "20180131 \t'
```

The unterminated string from error message is `"20180131 \t`.

Instead, use `"` and escape the inner `"` with `\"`:

```
awk "/Date/ { print; print \"20180131 \t' '76.196 \t578.177 \t903.000\"; next }1" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `awk` doesn't like the way you are using quotation marks. Glancing at your `awk` statement, I would point first to your frequent use of single-quotation marks within your print statement. `awk` is interpreting the single-quote after `\t` as marking the end of your entire `awk` program (that you began with a single-quote after the keyword `awk`), and at that point there was no closing double-quote for your print command (nor a close-brace for your `awk` statement).

The easier way to pass variables into an `awk` program is to use the command-line argument `-V`, eg. `awk -V pdy="$PDY" -V mean="$mean", and then use`pdy`and`mean`as native`awk` variables. With this method, there will be no need for most of your quoting.